# Exclude *.data.spec.ts file from unit testing

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, ts-jest

I'm struggling to find a simple answer on internet on how to exclude `*.data.spec.t`s from Jest tests.
I think this is happening in `jest.config.json` file and need to put something in `"testPathIgnorePatterns": []`, but I didn't find the correct RegEx (if not wrong) to exclude those `*.data.spec.ts` files.

Any clue?

Here is the path to the file: `src/app/features/settings/settings.data.spec.ts`.

Thanks in advance for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

To exclude all files with the name pattern "*.data.spec.ts" in the "src/app/features/settings" directory, you can use the following regular expression:

```
"testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/src/app/features/settings/*.data.spec.ts"
],
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working. The file is read by Jest. Even if I exclude it from tsconfig.spec.ts:
`{
  "include": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/*.data.spec.ts"]
}`